# How to make entire <td> area work as label for a radio button instead of only its text?

Tags: html

Currently I have:

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Header 1</th>
      <th>Header 2</th>
      <th></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><label for="myRadio">Info 1</label></td>
      <td><label for="myRadio">Info 2</label></td>
      <td><input type="radio" name="radios" id="myRadio"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><label for="myRadio2">Info 3</label></td>
      <td><label for="myRadio2">Info 4</label></td>
      <td><input type="radio" name="radios" id="myRadio2"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

This way if I click on "Info 1" or on "Info 2" the radio on the first row is selected. However if I click somewhere on the row that is not text it doesn't. How can I make it work? I have already tried putting the `<label>` tag before the `<tr>` tag and closing it after but it didn't work (the label wouldn't reference anything)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this style:

```css
label {
  display:block;
}
```

```html
<table border='1'>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Header 1</th>
      <th>Header 2</th>
      <th></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><label for="myRadio">Info 1</label></td>
      <td><label for="myRadio">Info 2</label></td>
      <td><input type="radio" name="radios" id="myRadio"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><label for="myRadio2">Info 3</label></td>
      <td><label for="myRadio2">Info 4</label></td>
      <td><input type="radio" name="radios" id="myRadio2"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Basically what this does is it tells your `label` to occupy the entire width of the table cell.

Also if you really want to take the ENTIRE width of the table cell, you might want to do `td { padding: 0; }`. Take note that this will affect how your cells look like and you should add the spacing to your cells contents instead.